# Pandas group by cumsum with a flag condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, cumsum

Assuming i have the following data frame

|  | date | flag | user | num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019-01-01 | 1 | a | 10 |
| 1 | 2019-01-02 | 0 | a | 20 |
| 2 | 2019-01-03 | 1 | b | 30 |
| 3 | 2019-03-04 | 1 | b | 40 |

I want to create a cumulative sum of the nums grouped by user only if flag == 1
so i will get this:

|  | date | flag | user | num | cumsum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019-01-01 | 1 | a | 10 | 10 |
| 1 | 2019-01-02 | 0 | a | 20 | 10 |
| 2 | 2019-01-03 | 1 | b | 30 | 30 |
| 3 | 2019-03-04 | 1 | b | 40 | 70 |

So far i was able to cumsum by flag, disregarding the group by user

```
df['cumsum'] = df[df['flag'] == 1 ]['num'].transform(pd.Series.cumsum)
```

or cumsum by user disregarding the flag

```
df['cumsum'] = df.groupby('user')['num'].transform(pd.Series.cumsum)
```

I need help making them work together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could multiply `num` by `flag` to make `num = 0` where `flag = 0`, group by `user`, and `cumsum`:

```
df['cumsum'] = df['num'].mul(df['flag']).groupby(df['user']).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
         date  flag user  num  cumsum
0  2019-01-01     1    a   10      10
1  2019-01-02     0    a   20      10
2  2019-01-03     1    b   30      30
3  2019-03-04     1    b   40      70
```

Answer (score 1):

With [`series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) to mark `num`==0 where flag is 0 then groupby+cumsum:

```
df['cumsum'] =  df['num'].where(df['flag'].eq(1),0).groupby(df["user"]).cumsum()
```

---

```
         date  flag user  num  cumsum
0  2019-01-01     1    a   10      10
1  2019-01-02     0    a   20      10
2  2019-01-03     1    b   30      30
3  2019-03-04     1    b   40      70
```